# Django wrong environ TZ variable

Tags: python, django, environ

i notice an issue, that *environ.get('TZ')* in django is different than system env TZ. In django it is always *"America/Chicago"*, but if i try `printenv TZ` directly on server, or use

```
python
import os
environ.get('TZ')
```

it is different, correct, my env TZ that I expect to see in django.
In django print all envs are same as system, except TZ. I misunderstand this =\

Answer (score 0):

Django does take in account `TIME_ZONE` env  for default time zone (timezone [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#default-time-zone-and-current-time-zone) ) variable which defaults to `'America/Chicago'` as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#std-setting-TIME_ZONE) ( in new templates to UTC )